# Fail to recursively delete directory in Alpine Linux when a nested file has a special character

Tags: c#, .net-core, special-characters, delete-directory

I'm running `dotnet-3.1` on `Alpine Linux 3.11.3` docker image.

My code is trying to delete some directory using

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete("path", recursive: true);
```

And I'm always getting the following exception:

```cs
System.IO.IOException: Directory not empty
   at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryInternal(DirectoryInfo directory, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
   at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectory(String fullPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String path, Boolean recursive)
```

Waiting for any amount of time and retrying any amount of time doesn't help. I managed to easily delete the file and directory from the shell `rm -rf path`.

The file name is something along the lines of `FOTO m'$'\242''n l.jpg`.

This is the only file in the directory that doesn't get deleted.

Any workaround or insights?

Comment: Do you get an error when calling `File.Delete()` on said file?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you report this to the .NET Core project?

Comment: Calling `File.Delete` directly on the file just silently fails. Indeed seem like a framework bug.

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4744